# Problemas con el preparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statements

Gracias por su atención quisiera preguntar cual es el problema en mi código, estoy realizando una consulta con Java pero al pasar al preparedStatement me dice que la conexión esta cerrada y no puede ejecutar mas operaciones (MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.), en la clase DAO tengo un constructor que posee la conexión.

Esta es la instrucción:

```
if (compraEntradaDTO.getMovilid().isEmpty()) {
            accionresult = helper.obtenerAccionResultFalla("VFCM0002");

        } else {

            BA506_DispositivosUsuarioDAO dispositivosDAO = new 
BA506_DispositivosUsuarioDAO(ds.obtenerConexion());
            List<BA506_DispositivosUsuarioDTO> dispositivos;
            dispositivos = 
dispositivosDAO.selectXidPhone(usuarioDTO.getBA505Id(), 
compraEntradaDTO.getMovilid());

            if (dispositivos.get(0).getBA506Pho() != 
compraEntradaDTO.getMovilid()) {
                accionresult = helper.obtenerAccionResultFalla("VFCM0002");
            }

        }
```

Y esta es la consulta:

```
public List<BA506_DispositivosUsuarioDTO> selectXidPhone(int id, String 
phone) throws Exception {

    List<BA506_DispositivosUsuarioDTO> l_resultado = null;

    String sql = "SELECT " + SelectAll();
    sql += " FROM " + TABLA;
    sql += " WHERE BA506Id = ? ";
    sql += " AND BA506Pho = ?";

    PreparedStatement preparedStatemtent = conexion.prepareStatement(sql);
    preparedStatemtent.setInt(1, id);
    preparedStatemtent.setString(2, phone);

    ResultSet rs = preparedStatemtent.executeQuery(sql);
    while (rs.next()) {
        BA506_DispositivosUsuarioDTO dispositivo = getSelectFull(rs);
        l_resultado.add(dispositivo);
    }

    return l_resultado;

}

}
```

Obviamente la conexión la he usado en operaciones anteriores a este trozo de código a diferentes clases pero no he presentado problema, puedo comentariar los if y el programa sigue su curso. No he podido hallar la raíz del problema. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

quitale el sql del preparedStatemtent:

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatemtent = conexion.prepareStatement(sql);
```

Y ponlo así:

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatemtent = conexion.prepareStatement();
```

Ya me cuentas!